# Prevent Xcode from building subprojects every time

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I have several subprojects in my project which are get built every time, even they are not changed and not in main project's target dependencies. Is there a way to prevent Xcode from doing this? It takes too much time for all the subprojects to build every time.

Comment: How many subtargets, and what hardware are you using?

Comment: 3 subtargets.please, find answer to my question below

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It would seem you have Xcode 4's "Find Implicit Dependencies" enabled. Note that this is enabled by *default*.

- Product > Edit Scheme…
- Build (in left column)
- **UNCHECK** "Find Implicit Dependencies"

Xcode will then only build the dependencies which are out of date and specified as dependencies (or dependencies of a dependency).

If you find that is not the case, then you may want to investigate what causes the build to retrigger (e.g. generated sources, relinking against dependencies which needed to be rebuilt, etc.).

Comment: @peetonn you're welcome :) i always work with that setting disabled.

Comment: This will cause the build failed if we switch from building for real devices to the simulators. In that case, "Find Implicit Dependencies"
 should be checked (temporarily). More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244908/no-such-module-when-simulator-but-when-use-device-it-can-find-it

Comment: Is this a great solution for projects using CocoaPods?