# No such module when simulator, but when use device it can find it

Tags: xcode, meteor, cocoapods

I got a project where I use some Pods, where one of them is Meteor.

I have installed with cocoapods with this podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'OpenTok', '~> 2.6'
pod 'Meteor', '~> 0.1'
```

And then open up the .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj
Then in my project I import Meteor in my AppDelegate.
When I choose a simulator and try to run/build it comes with the error "No such module 'Meteor'"

But then if I take my iPad and connect it and choose it as target, I can fine run/build.

I have not be able to find a solution for this yet.

Comment: what is the project name name you have given?

Comment: My project is just named HelloWorld?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same symptom after following these instructions to speed up my build:
[Prevent Xcode from building subprojects every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730159/prevent-xcode-from-building-subprojects-every-time)

I was able to run on a simulator again after reverting.

- Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme…
- Build (in left column)
- Make sure that "Find Implicit Dependencies" is Checked

Comment: What kind of error is this , though it solved my problem ,Thanks